# Sqlite3 corrupts some chars after importing

Tags: sqlite, csv, encoding

I have a tab-separated file with records like these:

```
no      Newcastle       1       NULL    NULL    NULL
uk      Ньюкасл 1       NULL    NULL    NULL
ja      ニューカッスル  1       NULL    NULL    NULL
```

To import them to sqlite, I use:

```
create table cities (country text, name text, count integer...);
.separator '    '
.import file cities
```

(where '    ' above contains a tab character). The file seems to be importing fine, but some non-ASCII chars get corrupted, especially at end of strings, and replaced with question marks.

```
no           Newcastle         1                NULL         NULL          NULL      
uk           Ньюкасл    1                NULL         NULL          NULL      
ja           ニューカッ?  1                NULL         NULL          NULL
```

The corruption occurs at import. I tried using **PRAGMA encoding = "UTF-8";** before importing, but it doesn't help. Any ideas?

**update per request from the user CL below**

Hexdump of a portion of the input file (the same portion as shown above with some additional numeric values which are irrelevant here; in the ASCII column the corrupted chars precede the "1" which follows the "ja"):

```
00008180  30 30 30 30 30 30 32 30  37 33 32 33 39 09 31 34  |0000002073239.14|
00008190  38 36 33 39 36 31 33 34  35 33 33 33 36 35 38 38  |8639613453336588|
000081a0  09 75 6b 09 d0 9d d1 8c  d1 8e d0 ba d0 b0 d1 81  |.uk.............|
000081b0  d0 bb 09 31 09 4e 55 4c  4c 09 4e 55 4c 4c 09 4e  |...1.NULL.NULL.N|
000081c0  55 4c 4c 0a 31 32 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  |ULL.120000000000|
000081d0  32 30 37 33 32 34 30 09  31 34 38 36 33 39 36 31  |2073240.14863961|
000081e0  33 34 35 33 33 33 36 35  38 38 09 6a 61 09 e3 83  |3453336588.ja...|
000081f0  8b e3 83 a5 e3 83 bc e3  82 ab e3 83 83 e3 82 b9  |................|
00008200  e3 83 ab 09 31 09 4e 55  4c 4c 09 4e 55 4c 4c 09  |....1.NULL.NULL.|
00008210  4e 55 4c 4c 0a 31 32 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  |NULL.12000000000|
00008220  30 32 30 37 33 32 34 31  09 31 34 38 36 33 39 36  |02073241.1486396|
```

Result of select hex(name) for the offending record:

```
hex(name)                  
--------------------------------------
31323030303030303030303032303733323430
```

Comment: What's the encoding of the input file?

Comment: It's UTF-8, and it displays normally in any editor I have here.

Comment: You can describe your problem to sqlite's mailing list `sqlite-users@mailinglists.sqlite.org` to get better quality help.

Comment: Show a hexdump of this portion of the input file, and the output of `SELECT hex(Name) FROM cities` for the offending string.

Comment: Done, please see the update to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with importing; the `sqlite3` command-line tool does not truncate strings correctly when using `.width`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I just figured the same out when investigating this issue with the sqlite-users mailing list.